Restore "Rebuild and open in container?" popup
When I opened my project that contains a devcontainer.json, I used to get a pop up that says something to the effect of "Folder contains a Dev Container configuration file. Rebuild and open in container?" I'm no longer seeing that popup. My guess is I inadvertently clicked the "Don't show again button."
How do I get that pop up back?
Thanks!
Searched google without success.

Seems solved in devcontainer extension v0.375.0
